# How to find the locus of this equation?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I am a beginner in math, and am stuck by this problem. The problem is,

> Find the locus of the point of intersection of the lines, $x\cos\alpha$ + $y\sin\alpha$ = *a* and $x\sin\alpha$ - $y\cos\alpha$ = *b* , where "alpha" is a variable.

What they did, is that they eliminated alpha from the equations and got a relation that x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2.

But what i did is , i found out the value of x from equation 1, then i put that in equation 2 and i get y from there, then i again put y back in equation 1 and i get a relation between x and y, but i also get $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ in my answer with that! What does this mean? Howard where is my answer different from the answer that’s given in the book?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You goal is to find the set of all $\{x,y\}$ that meet the following criteria:

$x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha = a\\
x \sin \alpha - y \cos \alpha = b$

These are perpendicular lines that intersect in a point.  But as we allow $\alpha$ to move, that point of intersection moves.

If we can eliminate $\alpha$ then we would have a set of points for all $\alpha$

$x \cos^2 \alpha + y \cos \alpha \sin \alpha = a \cos \alpha\\
x \sin^2 \alpha - y \cos \alpha \sin \alpha= b\sin \alpha$

$x = a \cos\alpha + b \sin \alpha$

Now here is where I would get a little tricky

$x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos\alpha \cos \phi + b \sin \alpha \sin \phi $

where $\phi$ is a function of $a,b$ i.e. $\phi = tan^{-1} \frac ba$
but since $a,b$ are constants, $\phi$ is also constant.

$x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos(\alpha-\phi)$

and if we solve for $y$ then:

$y = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \sin(\alpha-\phi)$

and that is the parametric equation of a circle.

But supposing you don't subscribe such witchcraft.

$x = a \cos\alpha + b \sin \alpha\\
y = a \sin\alpha - b \cos \alpha\\
x^2 = a^2 \cos^2 \alpha + b^2 \sin^2 \alpha + 2ab \cos\alpha \sin\alpha\\
y^2 = a^2 \sin^2 \alpha + b^2 \cos^2 \alpha - 2ab \cos\alpha \sin\alpha\\
x^2 + y^2 = (a^2 + b^2)$

Answer (score 0):

You ended up with a formula that had $x$, $y$ and $\alpha$.  But you started with two such formulas, so you're no better off than when you started.

The point of eliminating $\alpha$ from the equations is to get a relation between $x$ and $y$ that does not have $\alpha$ in it.

Alternatively, you could get both $x$ and $y$ as functions of $\alpha$:

$$ \eqalign{x &= a \cos(\alpha) + b \sin(\alpha)\cr
            y &= a \sin(\alpha) - b \cos(\alpha)}$$

That would be a **parametric** representation of the locus.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. But, the x and y which are present in the earlier equations were of independent equations. But the relation of x and y which i have found, is the  relation among the locus and not the independent line, so how can you say that  “You ended up with a formula that had x
x
, y
y
 and α
α
. But you started with two such formulas, so you're no better off than when you started."